# Get an attachment which I click and drag to drop?

Tags: c#, .net, outlook, email-attachments

Using Outlook Interop I do not understand how to get (C#) an attachment that I clicked on and then drag it in order to drop.

"AttachmentSelection" property of Explorer returns selected attachments but not clicked.

For example, I have "demo.xlsm" attachment selected and then I click on demo.rar (without leaving the mouse) dragging it to some winform app... So the demo.rar is not actually selected (but demo.xlsm does).

My question is how to get the clicked attachment?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could get selected attachment with the below code:

```
 public void DoSomething(Office.IRibbonControl control)
{
    var window = plugin.Application.ActiveWindow();
    var attachsel = window.AttachmentSelection();

    int? index = null;
    if (attachsel.count > 0)
    {
        var attachment = attachsel[1];
        index = attachment.Index;
    }

    var explorer = plugin.Application.ActiveExplorer();
    var selection = explorer.Selection;

    if ((selection.Count > 0) && (index != null))   
    {
        object selectedItem = selection[1];
        var mailItem = selectedItem as Outlook.MailItem;
        foreach (Outlook.Attachment attach in mailItem.Attachments)
        {
            if (attach.Index == index)
            {
                attach.SaveAsFile(Path.Combine(@"c:\temp\", attach.FileName));
            }
        }

    }
}
```

For more information, you could refer to this link:

[VSTO Outlook: Get selected attachment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15205237/vsto-outlook-get-selected-attachment)